# Unable to send large stream of data using UDP in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a small project, where i need to read one line from a file in client and send it to server. following is the details of my file.

```
Jeevans-MacBook-Pro:udp jeevansrikar$ ls -ll number.txt 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jeevansrikar  staff  5197498 Oct 23 00:04 number.txt
Jeevans-MacBook-Pro:udp jeevansrikar$ head number.txt 
64434
84511
80655
95690
41954
82049
62288
52560
37556
47627
```

Server

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPServer
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9883);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                  InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                  int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                  sendData = sentence.getBytes();
                  DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                  new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                  System.out.println(serverSocket.getSendBufferSize());
                  serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
               }

      }
}
```

Client:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      String fileName = "number.txt";
      String line = null;
      DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
      InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
      byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
      byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
      String modifiedSentence = null;

      try{
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            sendData = line.getBytes();
            System.out.println("To Server :"+line);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9883);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("From Server :" + modifiedSentence);


        }


      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
          System.out.println(
              "Unable to open file '" + 
              fileName + "'");                
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
          System.out.println(
              "Error reading file '" 
              + fileName + "'");                  
          // Or we could just do this: 
          // ex.printStackTrace();
      }

      clientSocket.close();
   }
}
```

i have to use UDP transfer protocol to transfer each line from client to server. After sending certain 100s of lines server is not accepting new line, data transmission was stopped. Is there any UDP buffer size to increase to accept large data transfer?

Comment: You provided neither client nor server side code, how on earth are we supposed to diagnose your problem?

Comment: Are you aware that there is no guaranteed delivery in UDP?